# Extracting frames of real time video feed in React Native

Tags: react-native, tensorflow, expo

I am working on an image detection application that shows a real time video feed and sends a couple of frames per second to the backend, where objects are detected using an AI. I am using react native for the frontend and can't seem to find a suitable way to store a frame from the camera feed in a variable and send it to the backend API.

I tried Expo's camera but it is not applicaple for this case, CameraWithTensors automatically transforms the image into a tensor - which i also dont want as i want to perform preprocessing in the backend. It sounds simple enough - but almost all similar projects either dont use a backend, or use react.
Any ideas how to tackle this - keeping in mind that the process should be as fast as possible so more frames can be analyzed?